# Debug erlang with emacs and distel

Tags: debugging, erlang

I'm new to erlang and had a look at [this tutorial article](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070528.html).

My env is Emacs24 and R15B01.

I do all the same like following:

1. C-c C-z to open erlang shell
2. c([my_module.erl],[debug_info]) to compile code with debug info
3. C-c C-d L to load module (Before this, I opened a terminal to start an erlang node)
4. C-c C-d i to enter interpreted successfully
5. C-c C-d b to add breakpoint

The first time when I do all these, the debugger is perfect and I can see everything I want.
But when I add another breakpoint, it cannot take effect.

Is there any step I've missed?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, I've done all these steps after add another breakpoint.

Comment: Does it show any errors? Or just ignores it?

Comment: @blinkov No. I've debug for a long time with dbg, so let it go.